# How can I open an application/download it from play store while click a link from a message

Tags: android

I have a requirement as below:

1. A message will receive in my phone with a link.
2. If i click in the link the application should open or go to play store if the application is not installed in my phone.
3. If the application is opened, then a user creation page should open.
4. If user not opened this application from the link then home page/login page should open instead of user creation page.

   How can i implement this requirement ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [FireBase Dynamic Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/):

> When a user opens one of your Dynamic Links, if your app isn't yet installed, the user is sent to the Play Store or App Store to install your app (unless you specify otherwise), and your app opens. You can then retrieve the link that was passed to your app and handle the link as appropriate for your app.

The `Dynamic Link` is even more powerful. If you open the link in your PC, it can open a redirect link to whatever link you want.

This is the format of `Dynamic Link`: https://abc123.app.goo.gl/?link=https://example.com/&apn=com.example.android&ibi=com.example.ios

Comment: Thanks for the update. I want to know one more thing.  If i am open the application from the link then i want to go to a different screen other than the home page.(Usually application starts with home page when user open application not from the link)

Comment: you need to pass data with your link. Something likes: `https://example.com?movieid=1` --> you can parse this link to get `movieId` when user opens your app from `DynamicLink`